# is it possible run rancher cattle and kubernetes agents running at same time on a host?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, cattle

[image]

I would like to try Kubernetes, I currently have my environments with the **cattle** orchestation running on each host. Does somebody try to run both on the same host?.

Comment: Here is a documentation about the answer that I get: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.5/en/kubernetes/

Comment: in case that you want to rollback to Cattle, Just delete the Kubernetes Stack. https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6265

Answer (score 1):

You can covert a "Cattle" environment to a "Kubernetes" environment by installing the Kubernetes Stack.

Top Menu > Catalog > Library > [Search for Kubernetes] View Details > Customize the options (if needed) > Launch.